# Is there a way to communicate with Raspberry pi 3 using python 3 and MacOS?

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, raspberry-pi

I have tried many different ways, but none of them worked. If you have a solution, can you provide a step-by-step description about it?

Comment: What have you tried? Example code? In what why are you trying to get them to communicate?

Comment: Please read the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) articles. Do you think it would be okay to put some effort into asking? Do you think it is okay to ask others to do the research? And do you think we should feed you with the answers from a silver platter? At least present us what you have tried so far.

Comment: Yes, you can use HTTP.

Answer (score 1):

Use python [Socket](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html) module. Here you can find [Socket's documentation for Python 3.x](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_networking.htm). And here you can jump right into [Simple code example](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TcpCommunication).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18522860)

Comment: But this question seems to be too broad to find essential parts of e.g. Socket module documentation.

Comment: I also think that even if the links doesn't work any longer... The used words are giving a good information to find a solution.